# how to use the CreateProcess function in Visual Studios

Tags: c, visual-studio, winapi

I've seen some examples of the CreateProcess() function on Stack Overflow, but I could not get the examples to work.  I'm using Visual Studio but programming the straight C.  Here is my latest attempt.  I can get it to compile and execute, but I can't get it to start the application:

```
PROCESS_INFORMATION ProcessInfo; //This is what we get as an [out] parameter
STARTUPINFO StartupInfo; //This is an [in] parameter
ZeroMemory(&StartupInfo, sizeof(StartupInfo));

StartupInfo.cb = sizeof StartupInfo ; 

hr = CreateProcess((NULL, (LPTSTR) "C:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe"), NULL,  
                    NULL,NULL,FALSE,0,NULL,
                    NULL,&StartupInfo,&ProcessInfo);

                int error_1 = 0;
                if(!hr)
                {
                    error_1 = GetLastError();
                }
```

When I read 'error_1', it returns a '2', which based upon the System Error Codes indicates that "The system cannot find the file specified.".  However, I'm sure the path is correct as I can use the path from the command line to start "Notepad".  I can't see what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Try to exchange the first two parameters. The 2nd parameter cannot be a literal string, but the 1st can.

Comment: It seems odd to be using the comma operator for the first argument to `CreateProcess()`.  You have `(NULL, (LPTSTR) "C:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe")` as the first argument, which evaluates `NULL` and throws it away, and then evaluates the cast of the string.  Check MSDN on [`CreateProcess()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx) — you don't specify a command line (but I've no idea whether that matters or not).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler You're right - I didn't realize the additional parentheses. I'm sure it isn't intended this way.

Comment: @SBS: It's enough to confuse anybody.  It appears that `CreateProcess()` takes 10 arguments; it is actually given 10 arguments in the code shown. It appears that setting the command line (second parameter) to NULL is OK; there are rules around what that means.  I don't have a Windows machine to experiment on, so I can't help the OP much more.

Comment: So maybe this modified call will do the trick: `hr = CreateProcess((LPTSTR) "C:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe", NULL, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &StartupInfo, &ProcessInfo);`

Comment: The problem, well one of them, is your cast. You are telling a big lie to the compiler about the type of your string literal.

Comment: You should not cast the 2nd argument of `CreateProcess()` to `LPTSTR`, because it is a string literal and `CreateProcess()` may modify the string. A string literal can't be modified because it is stored in read-only memory. Instead store the path in a character array and pass that array to the function. Also you should enclose the path in double-quotes to allow the use of spaces in the path. Space character is reserved to separate path from command-line arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get rid of the extra parenthesis around the first 2 parameter values you are passing.

But, more importantly, you need to get rid of the `LPTSTR` type-cast.  If your project is configured to compile for Unicode, `CreateProcess()` will map to `CreateProcessW()`, and `LPTSTR` will map to `wchar_t*`, thus you will be type-casting a narrow `const char[]` literal to a `wchar_t*` pointer and end up passing garbage to `CreateProcessW()`, which could easily account for the error you are seeing.  The correct way to create a `TCHAR[]` string literal is to use the [`TEXT()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374074.aspx) macro instead of a typecast (see [Working with Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff381407.aspx) on MSDN for more details):

```
hr = CreateProcess(NULL, TEXT("C:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe"), NULL,  
                    NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL,
                    NULL, &StartupInfo, &ProcessInfo);
```

However, pay attention to the [`CreateProcess()` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425.aspx):

> *lpCommandLine* [in, out, optional]
>   The command line to be executed. The maximum length of this string is 32,768 characters, including the Unicode terminating null character. If `lpApplicationName` is NULL, the module name portion of lpCommandLine is limited to `MAX_PATH` characters.
>
> **The Unicode version of this function, `CreateProcessW`, can modify the contents of this string. Therefore, this parameter cannot be a pointer to read-only memory (such as a const variable or a literal string). If this parameter is a constant string, the function may cause an access violation.**

You can do the following to avoid that:

```
TCHAR szCmdLine[] = TEXT("C:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe");
hr = CreateProcess(NULL, szCmdLine, NULL,  
                    NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL,
                    NULL, &StartupInfo, &ProcessInfo);
```

Or:

```
WCHAR szCmdLine[] = L"C:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe";
hr = CreateProcessW(NULL, szCmdLine, NULL,  
                    NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL,
                    NULL, &StartupInfo, &ProcessInfo);
```

Otherwise, use the ANSI version of `CreateProcess()` directly, which you can safely pass a string literal to:

```
hr = CreateProcessA(NULL, "C:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe", NULL,  
                    NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL,
                    NULL, &StartupInfo, &ProcessInfo);
```

On a side note, you don't need to specify the full path to `notepad.exe`, as Windows knows where it is located.  You can use `"notepad.exe"` by itself.

However, if you do specify the full path, you have to take into account the bitness of your app.  If your app is compiled for 32-bit, and is run on a 64-bit system, `C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe` will redirect to `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\notepad.exe`, which is the 32-bit version of Notepad.  If you want to run the 64-bit version of Notepad, you would have to use `C:\Windows\Sysnative\notepad.exe` instead, per the WOW64 documentation:

[File System Redirector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187.aspx)

> The `%windir%\System32` directory is reserved for 64-bit applications. Most DLL file names were not changed when 64-bit versions of the DLLs were created, so 32-bit versions of the DLLs are stored in a different directory. WOW64 hides this difference by using a file system redirector.
>
> **In most cases, whenever a 32-bit application attempts to access `%windir%\System32`, the access is redirected to `%windir%\SysWOW64`**. Access to `%windir%\lastgood\system32` is redirected to `%windir%\lastgood\SysWOW64`. Access to `%windir%\regedit.exe` is redirected to `%windir%\SysWOW64\regedit.exe`.
>
> ...
>
> **32-bit applications can access the native system directory by substituting `%windir%\Sysnative` for `%windir%\System32`**. WOW64 recognizes `Sysnative` as a special alias used to indicate that the file system should not redirect the access. This mechanism is flexible and easy to use, therefore, it is the recommended mechanism to bypass file system redirection. Note that 64-bit applications cannot use the `Sysnative` alias as it is a virtual directory not a real one.

`Sysnative` only works in a 32-bit app running inside of the WOW64 emulator.  you can use `System32` in a 32-bit app running on a 32-bit system, and a 64-bit app running on a 64-bit system:

```
TCHAR szCmdLine[MAX_PATH];

#ifndef _WIN64
BOOL bIsWow64Process = FALSE;
if (IsWow64Process(GetCurrentProcess(), &bIsWow64Process) && bIsWow64Process)
    lstrcpy(szCmdLine, TEXT("C:\\Windows\\Sysnative\\notepad.exe"));
else
#endif
    lstrcpy(szCmdLine, TEXT("C:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe"));

hr = CreateProcess(NULL, szCmdLine, NULL,  
                    NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL,
                    NULL, &StartupInfo, &ProcessInfo);
```

However, you should take into account that not everyone installs Windows in the `C:\Windows` folder, so you should ask Windows where the System folder is actually located:

```
TCHAR szSysDir[MAX_PATH];

#ifndef _WIN64
BOOL bIsWow64Process = FALSE;
if (IsWow64Process(GetCurrentProcess(), &bIsWow64Process) && bIsWow64Process)
{
    TCHAR szWinDir[MAX_PATH];
    GetWindowsDirectory(szWinDir, MAX_PATH);
    PathCombine(szSysDir, szWinDir, TEXT("Sysnative");
}
else
#endif
    GetSystemDirectory(szSysDir, MAX_PATH);

TCHAR szCmdLine[MAX_PATH];
PathCombine(szCmdLine, szSysDir, TEXT("notepad.exe");

hr = CreateProcess(NULL, szCmdLine, NULL,  
                    NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL,
                    NULL, &StartupInfo, &ProcessInfo);
```

Comment: I would add that the path should be enclosed in double quotation marks. While it works in this specific case, because the path doesn't contain spaces, it won't work with pathes like `C:\\Program Files\\Sub Folder\\Some.exe`.

Comment: Thank you Remy.  I removed the parenthesis that were combining what I thought was two parameters into one and  modified the code based upon your suggestion.  Worked like a charm.

Comment: Thanks guys for the support.